# Using python is there a way to dynamically show checkbox values with gradio?

Tags: python, checkbox, gradio

I want to use a model on an image where I detect objects. Then I want to show the detected objects as checkbox values. The user can then select the objects he wants to run the next model on (by using the checkbox). As I just wanted to make a quick application for demonstration purposes, I thought of using gradio for this small task.

This code shows what I would like to achieve:

```
import gradio as gr


def detect_objects(input_image):
    object_detector = ObjectDetector()
    detections = object_detector(input_image)

    list = []
    for detection in detections:
        label = detection['names']
        list.append(label)

    return list

def apply_next(input_image, selected_objects):
    
    something = apply_next_model(input_image, selected_objects)

    return Image.fromarray(something)


with gr.Blocks() as app:

        inp_image = gr.Image(type="numpy", label="Upload Content Image")

        detect_button = gr.Button("Detect Objects")

        detected_image = gr.Image(label="Detected Objects")
        object_list = gr.CheckboxGroup(label="Select Objects for model")
        model_button = gr.Button("Apply next model")
        end_image = gr.Image()

        detect_button.click(fn=detect_objects, inputs=inp_image, outputs=[object_list])
        model_button.click(fn=apply_next, inputs=[inp_image, object_list], outputs=end_image)


app.launch()
```

I have tried a few different methods using gradio states and such but I just couldn't make it work. In the gradio documentation I also did not find this specific case. I hope you can help me!